Why does pip install throw an error in tomli source?
I am a newby in python or coding in general. I am not even good with the terminology. But I need to work with the stemtool (https://github.com/pycroscopy/stemtool) to process electron microscopy images. The examples presented are exactly what I want to do. But no matter how much I tried and read, I could not make it work. I am on windows and using vscode. Python version is 3.9.13 and pip version is 24.0. I am trying to make it work in a virtual environment.
For instance, this project uses pyproject.toml builder (excuse my misuse of terminology, if there is) and it seems if I run "pip install -e ." it should do something but what I get is the junk error below. Also I tried to things with the config.py file but "import stemtool" does give an error as well. Can someone spoonfeed me on this. I am aware that I am asking for a lot, but I am desperate.
Help would be appreciated.
Error message:
(.venv) PS C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\stemtool-master> python -m pip install .[dependencies]                                 
Processing c:\users\furkan\desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\stemtool-master
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 76, in resolve
    collected = self.factory.collect_root_requirements(root_reqs)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 534, in collect_root_requirements
    reqs = list(
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 490, in _make_requirements_from_install_req
    cand = self._make_base_candidate_from_link(
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 228, in _make_base_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 290, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 222, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 301, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 525, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 640, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 71, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 37, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self.req.load_pyproject_toml()
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 516, in load_pyproject_toml
    pyproject_toml_data = load_pyproject_toml(
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\pyproject.py", line 64, in load_pyproject_toml      
    pp_toml = tomli.loads(f.read())
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 102, in loads
    pos = key_value_rule(src, pos, out, header, parse_float)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 326, in key_value_rule        
    pos, key, value = parse_key_value_pair(src, pos, parse_float)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 369, in parse_key_value_pair  
    pos, value = parse_value(src, pos, parse_float)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 616, in parse_value
    return parse_array(src, pos, parse_float)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 420, in parse_array
    pos, val = parse_value(src, pos, parse_float)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 620, in parse_value
    return parse_inline_table(src, pos, parse_float)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 445, in parse_inline_table    
    pos, key, value = parse_key_value_pair(src, pos, parse_float)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 360, in parse_key_value_pair  
    pos, key = parse_key(src, pos)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 374, in parse_key
    pos, key_part = parse_key_part(src, pos)
  File "C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\pythonfiles\stemtool-master5\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tomli\_parser.py", line 404, in parse_key_part        
    raise suffixed_err(src, pos, "Invalid initial character for a key part")
pip._vendor.tomli.TOMLDecodeError: Invalid initial character for a key part (at line 6, column 34)

I am trying to get results as shown in example files in the repo, alas I am far from it.
